# java restful web services retrieving post data

Tags: json, web-services, post, parameters, android-volley

I am getting a JSON object POST request from android volley.I am trying to read the json using the following code.

```
    @POST
    @Path("/driver/insertTripLog")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String insertTripLog(InputStream incomingData) throws Exception
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incomingData));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Parsing: - ");
        }
        String data=sb.toString();
        System.out.println("Data Received: " +data );
     return data;
}
```

The output i am getting json object but the special characters are encoded with %XX  format.

**Sample Output:**

```
json=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22value%22%7D%5D
```

how to read properly post json data sent from volley.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#URLDecoder%28%29) class to handle the percent encoded content which you are seeing:

```
String data = sb.toString();
data = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(data, "UTF-8");
```

**Output:**

```
json=[{"name":"value"}]
```

Comment: in output i don't want to display json=

Comment: Then use `data.substring(5)` to remove the leading text `json=`.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen if i want to send multiple parameters in post request from android volley how can i read that multiple parameters in rest webservices

Comment: @venkatasivaiah I think you should ask a new question for this.  And you should ideally mark my answer correct if it solved your first problem.

Comment: your answer is working correct. And i have new question that is if i want to send multiple parameters in post request from android volley how can i read that multiple parameters in rest webservices  with small example